# A plug in to watch the javascript functions is runing in that certain time

Tags: javascript

Like in fiddler you can watch the logs between client and server. Like fiddler; which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. I want to inspect all traffic happening on the client side JavaScript that runs on a page.

Best wishes
bk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this best using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox :)

When you open firebug, open the **net** panel and you can see all traffic the browser's dealing with.  If you want just the AJAX requests, there's a bar under the main tabs, select **XHR**.

There's more info available on the [net section of the firebug site](http://getfirebug.com/network).

If I misunderstood the question and you want to see all javascript activity, then Firebug does this as well, just open the **Console** panel and click **profile**, this will let you see what's happening on the client with all javascript.

As an aside, if you need an IE specific tool, I'd *really* recommend [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/) (also free!).  It's a very in-depth profiler specifically tailored for IE.